# How to load png images quicker - kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a game with different images popping on screen every few seconds and the first time each image is being loaded, the game stops and is like it would go on pause. 
Now I am loading it like this:

```
class Fruit(Widget):
    def __init__(self, imagename, size, **kwargs): 
        super(Fruit, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.size = size
            self.x = self.center_x
            self.y = self.center_y
            self.pos = (self.x, self.y)
            self.rect_bg = Rectangle(source=imagename,
                                 pos=self.pos,
                                 size=self.size)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg_pos)
            self.rect_bg.pos = self.pos

    def update_bg_pos(self, instance, value):
        self.rect_bg.pos = value
```

So every time I need to create a fruit I use this class and give it a random image and position:

```
def add_fruit(self, *args):
        imagename = "fruit{}.png".format(randint(1,6))
        tmpFruit = Fruit(imagename=imagename, size(self.parent.height*0.067, self.parent.height*0.067))
        tmpFruit.x = randint(1, self.width-40)
        tmpFruit.y = randint(1, self.height-140)

        self.fruit_list.append(tmpFruit)
        self.add_widget(tmpFruit)
```

I saw loader and async image in kivy documentation but didn't understand how they work and how to use it in my code.
I would appreciate if anyone could tell me if any of those two will speed up the loading time or how to load an image from url.

Comment: check out the keep_data attribute of Images. Google 'kivy image' to get the docs(works for all kivy widget types) and look at the api(scroll down or click 'jump to api'). I believe you may be able to pre-load all images in say, the init of a class using this.

Comment: Did this work? Or make any difference for you?

Comment: I am not sure yet because it loads images fine on windows but lags on mac or android, where I haven't tried running the new version yet. I hope it works :) I am not sure if I used it correctly because I don't set an objects image through Image but use with canvas and Rectangle(source, size, pos, **keep_data=True**). It does not give me any errors so I assumed I can use it like this, but can I really?

Comment: It's possible that it would let you set this keyword argument without it meaning anything to the Rectangle.  Especially if it by default takes **kwargs as an argument,  and it doesn't clash with anything. However,  I guess it's worth a try. I do know that using keep_data with Image solved android speed issues for me in the past.